# Responsive Sharepoint List forms

Tags: mvc, responsive

I am new to SharePoint and my project requires forms to be filled by different users on different devices and we have chosen SharePoint lists for our solution.

By default the UI of the forms of SharePoint lists look very outdated and their customization via InfoPath can be cumbersome for each form and even then the results aren't standardized easily across all forms and they are not responsive.

The markup syntax behind forms is confusing and verbose and editing it will be a long-term maintenance issue.

I am experienced in Web Forms and MVC and I wonder if there is any way of making the SharePoint list forms responsive with Bootstrap. I already use Bootstrap in my master page for the SharePoint site and in site pages.

Is it possible to generate CRUD forms from a LocalDB via MVC scaffolding and somehow deploy the project as a SharePoint hosted solution?

I am open to any approach to responsive InfoPath forms, preferably via a front-end library and minimum in-code and markup customization.

Thank you

Comment: What's your SharePoint version?

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint Patterns and Practices (PnP) team which is an open source initiative coordinated by SharePoint engineering has released a responsive UI package for use with SharePoint 2013/2016/Online.

After setting this up your entire SharePoint will be responsive with respect to the view port of the device you are using.You can get the package and implementation details from the below Github link.

[Responsive UI](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.UI.Responsive)

[image]

**Updated as per Comment**

If you are looking to integrate it with your corporate intranet and do not intend to integrate it with a paid product, Stratus Forms is a viable responsive solution. It was developed by SharePoint MVP,Mark Rackely

[Stratus Forms](http://www.stratusforms.com/)

[Github Link](https://github.com/mrackley/StratusForms)

Comment: Thanks for this, however, this refers to responsive site features, whilst I am rather looking for making forms for SharePoint lists responsive.

Comment: Stratus Forms is an option. Check the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to try [Plumsail Forms](https://plumsail.com/forms/sharepoint-forms/). This is tool for designing fully responsive forms for SharePoint Modern UI. It provides a lot of controls: tabs, accordions, data tables, list or library for displaying and editing items from other lists, ink sketch control for leaving hand-written notes in a form.

It's not free but unlike Power Apps, Plumsail Form is licensed per domain and can be used by external users as well.